# Extract separate columns from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns

I am trying to extract the first names of the titles of the columns such as **pack_10**, **pack_18** and **pack_20** and group all of them with sum. Below you can see my data

```
df<-data.frame(  
              packs_10_value5=c(100,0,0,0,0),
              packs_18_value9=c(200,0,0,0,0),
              packs_20_value13=c(300,0,0,0,0),
              packs_10_value15=c(100,0,0,0,0),
              packs_18_value17=c(200,0,0,0,0),
              packs_20_value18=c(300,0,0,0,0)
              )

df
```

[image]

So can anybody help me with how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `split` the columns and apply `rowSums` by group:

```r
library(purrr)
split.default(df, f = gsub("_value.*", "", names(df))) %>% 
  map_dfc(rowSums)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  packs_10 packs_18 packs_20
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1      200      400      600
2        0        0        0
3        0        0        0
4        0        0        0
5        0        0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more convoluted/less elegant, but you could also create a `row_number` column, `pivot_longer` by all other columns, do the regex, aggregate by the clean column name and each row and `pivot_wider` back:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
  group_by(name = sub('_value\\d+', '', name), rn) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'name', values_from = 'value') %>%
  select(-rn)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  packs_10 packs_18 packs_20
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1      200      400      600
2        0        0        0
3        0        0        0
4        0        0        0
5        0        0        0
```